# Cant access Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I can't access Linux anymore in my dual boot, as my GRUB menu disappeared. I even tried using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+restart and selecting Ubuntu from the settings, but it didn't work. However, the partition for Linux is still there as shown in "Disk Management" in Windows 10. I am using a Sony multi-flip 13a laptop.

How do I fix this? Also, if I can't fix this, how do I get my data from my Linux install?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the other day.  Seems Windows is overwriting `/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` in the EFI partition to make the system boot straight into Windows (details [here](https://forum.freegamedev.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=7408)). To fix it:

1. Set the BIOS to BIOS mode (instead of UEFI mode)
2. Boot from a USB or CD with [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/)
3. Select "Everything"
4. Select `Ubuntu`, should be right above `Advanced options for Ubuntu`
5. Once in Ubuntu, run `sudo apt install --reinstall grub-common grub2-common grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin`
6. Keep your [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) with your laptop, as you will probably be doing this a lot, as "Microsoft <strike>Hates</strike>Loves Linux" ;) (they only "love" Linux when it's inside Windows, apparently.)